# File server works for first upload, but not second

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have a file server that correctly checks for allowed filetypes and sizes and places the file on the server. If multiple allowed files are uploaded the files are zipped and the zip is placed on the server.

This all works. The page is ajax-ified so you should be able to use the form a second time, but it always fails on the second submit.

The response from upload.php for the second post is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload(
null,
"The file you attempted to upload is not allowed: K",
[],
1,
["K"],
[""]);
</script>
```

Here are my index.php and upload.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>PTPsubs</title>
   <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function startUpload(){
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      return true;
}

function stopUpload(code,message,path,numFiles,fileName,ext){
    var output = '';    
    if (code == 1){
        output += 'The file was uploaded successfully!<br/>';
    }
    else {
        output = message;
    }


    result = '<span class="msg">'+output+'<\/span><br/><br/>';

    document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<label>File: <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" /><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';
    document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = path;      
    return true;   
}
</script>   
</head>

<body>
       <img src="style/images/ptpsubs3.gif" alt="ptpsubs" align="absmiddle" class="displayed" />
        <div id="sidediv">
            <ul>
                <li>Allowed file types: .srt, .idx, .sub, .txt
                <li>Multiple files uploaded at once will return a link to a zip archive of those files
            </ul> 
        </div><!--close the sidediv-->
        <div id="container">        
            <div id="content">                
                    <!--form starts here-->
                    <form action="upload.php" id="group" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();" >
                         <p id="f1_upload_process">Loading...<br/><img src="loader.gif" /><br/></p>
                         <p id="f1_upload_form" align="center"><br/>
                             <label>File:  
                                  <input name="myfile[]" type="file" size="30" multiple="multiple" />
                             </label>
                             <label>
                                 <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" multiple="multiple" />
                             </label>
                         </p>

                         <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
                    </form>
                    <!--form ends here-->
            </div>
             <!--<div id="footer"><a href="" target="_blank">PTPsubs</a></div>-->
        </div>
        <div id="link"></div>            
</body>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
    /* creates a compressed zip file */
    function create_zip($files = array(),$localnames=array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
  //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
  if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
  //vars
  $valid_files = array();
  //if files were passed in...
  if(is_array($files)) {
    //cycle through each file
    foreach($files as $file) {
      //make sure the file exists
      if(file_exists($file)) {
        $valid_files[] = $file;
      }
    }
  }
  //if we have good files...
  if(count($valid_files)) {
    //create the archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
      return false;
    }
    //add the files
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($valid_files); $i++) {
      $zip->addFile($valid_files[$i],$localnames[$i]);
    }
    //debug
    //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

    //close the zip -- done!
    $zip->close();

    //check to make sure the file exists
    return file_exists($destination);
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}


    //database
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $database="";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $message = '';
    $code = array();
    $fileName = array();
    $ext = array();
    $tmpName = array();
    $path = array();
    $target_path = array();
    $prefix = substr(md5(time()),0,7); //new name of the file
    $pass = true;

    $count = count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {   
        //file info
        $fileName[$i] = $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
        $ext[$i] = pathinfo($fileName[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // Get the extension from the filename.
        $tmpName[$i]  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $fileSize[$i] = $_FILES['myfile']['size'][$i];
        $fileType[$i] = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i];  

       // Edit upload location here
        $destination_path = './files/';
        $allowed_filetypes = array('idx','sub','txt','srt');
        $max_filesize = 5242880; //bytes

        $target_path[$i] = $destination_path . $prefix .".".$ext[$i];

        // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
        if(!in_array($ext[$i],$allowed_filetypes)){
            $code[$i] = 2;
            $message = "The file you attempted to upload is not allowed: ".$fileName[$i];
            $pass=false;}

       // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
        else if(filesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i]) > $max_filesize){
            $code[$i] = 3;
            $message = "The file you attempted to upload is too large.";
            $pass=false;}

        else if(!file_exists($destination_path)){
            $code[$i] = 4;
            $message = "The upload path does not exist";
            $pass=false;}

       // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
        else if(!is_writable($destination_path)){
            $code[$i] = 5;
            $message = "You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.";
            $pass=false;}



    }//closes for loop

    if($pass==true)
    {
        //NOW DO THE UPLOAD
        if($count==1)//single file upload
        {
            @move_uploaded_file($tmpName[0], $target_path[0]);

            $file_info = pathinfo($fileName[0]);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Files SET 
                        uploader_ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                        File_Name = '".$fileName[0]."',
                        File_Type = '".$fileType[0]."',
                        File_Size = '".$fileSize[0]."',
                        File_Hash = '".$prefix.".".$file_info['extension']."',
                        File_Extension = '".$file_info['extension']."'";

            $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);    
            // If the query was successful, give success message
            if(!$sqlresult){
                $return_code = 6;
                $return_message = "Could not add this file.";//not actually displayed
                 exit;}
            else{
                $return_message =  "New file successfully added.";//not actually displayed
                $return_code = 1;
                $path[0] = 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $target_path[0] . '" title="Your File">here</a><br/>';  }//code = 1
        }//$count=1

        else//zip it because its multiple files
        { 
            $ext = "zip";
            $target = './files/'.$prefix.".zip";
            $zip_file = create_zip($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['myfile']['name'],$target);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Files SET 
                        uploader_ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                        File_Name = '".$fileName[0]."',
                        File_Type = '".filetype($target)."',
                        File_Size = '".filesize($target)."',
                        File_Hash = '".$prefix.".zip"."',
                        File_Extension = '".$ext."'";

            $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);    
            // If the query was successful, give success message
            if(!$sqlresult){
                $return_code = 6;
                $return_message = "Could not add this file.";//not actually displayed
                 exit;}
            else{
                $return_message =  "New file successfully added.";//not actually displayed
                $return_code = 1;
                $path[0] = 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $target. '" title="Your File">here</a><br/>';   }//code = 1
        }
    }//pass=true
    sleep(1);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopUpload(
<?php echo json_encode($return_code); ?>,
<?php echo json_encode($message); ?>,
<?php echo json_encode($path); ?>,
<?php echo json_encode($count); ?>,
<?php echo json_encode($fileName); ?>,
<?php echo json_encode($ext); ?>);
</script>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: check your `$_FILES` array with `var_dump`, maybe it will give more hints.

Answer (score 0):

You are having that error because of this line of code

```
    $allowed_filetypes = array('idx','sub','txt','srt');
    $max_filesize = 5242880; //bytes

    $target_path[$i] = $destination_path . $prefix .".".$ext[$i];

    // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
    if(!in_array($ext[$i],$allowed_filetypes)){
        $code[$i] = 2;
        $message = "The file you attempted to upload is not allowed: ".$fileName[$i];
        $pass=false;}
```

Possible Reasons

A. The file name you are trying to upload `$fileName[$i]` is showing "K" which means it has no extension. Please try and rename the file properly

B. You are uploading file with Wrong extension

C. `in_array` is case sensitive so if you have file extension with TXT != txt

Solution

```
   if(!in_array(strtolower($ext[$i]),$allowed_filetypes)){
```

Lastly ... I think its saver to use file type

I hope this helps

Thanks :)